# Ansible ansible.builtin.expect | requirement: pexpect

Tags: ansible, pexpect

Currently, I am trying to use the ansible.builtin.expect.

Here is my usecase:

```
- name: Set password for built-in user
    expect: command: '/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password" -f' 
    responses: Enter value for bootstrap.password: 'test'
```

To use ansible.builtin.expect I have to install:

python >= 2.6

pexpect >= 3.3

I have Python 2.7.5 installed, but if i want to install pexpect, it only installs version 2.3.

To install pexpect i use:

```
- name: Install pexpect module
  yum:
    name: pexpect
    state: latest
```

Does anyone know, how I am able to install pexpect version 3.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not installing directly the pip version matching your requirement:

```yaml
- name: Install pexpect throuhg pip
  become: true
  pip:
    name: "pexpect>=3.3"
    state: present
```

Comment: Thank you, that was simple!

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe:

```
- name: 'install pexpect'
  become: true
  become_user: 'root'
  yum:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
    enablerepo: 'standard'
  with_items:
    - 'pexpect'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The error from this try is:  "Repository standard not found."

Comment: you should check what yum repos are available and which contain pexpect.

ie:
see your `/etc/yum/repos.conf`

`yum --enablerepo=rhel7u6 list |grep pexpect`